# How to copy and save an image into a new folder?

Tags: python, tkinter

So far, I've only managed to prompt the user for an image:

```
def addImage(event=None):
    fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename() 
    return fileName
```

As far as I know, this only returns the path of the image. How would I be able to let the user choose an image from their personal drive and then save it into a new folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `shutil` module to move or copy files to different locations

```
import shutil

destination = "/some/destination/path"

def addImage(event=None):
    fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename() 
    shutil.copy(fileName, destination)
    return fileName
```

`shutil` also has functions for moving files instead of copying them, and functions for copying or moving full directories as well.

[`shutil` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)